# How EventGrid multicasts to multiple endpoints?

Tags: azure-eventgrid

The following documentation page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/overview

... states that:

> You can use filters to route specific events to different endpoints,
> **multicast** to multiple endpoints

Is the documentation accurate? If yes, how exactly can I configure EventGrid to multicast an specific event to to different endpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Event Grid supports delivering an event message in the *FAN-OUT* pattern, where each destination endpoint has **own** delivery metadata such as a subscription.

Therefor the AEG cannot deliver an event message to the destination targets in the multicast manner.

However, you can deliver an event message to the destination resource such as an Azure Service Bus (queue/topic) and then multicast it between your destination endpoints based on the needs.

Comment: Thank you for help. I am aware of the workaround. I just wanted to validate the statement quoted from the documentation. I the AEG documentation reference  to "multicast" pattern inaccurate and needs to be corrected?

Comment: you said "Azure Event Grid supports delivering an event message in the FAN-OUT pattern". How exactly FAN-OUT pattern works? To my understanding, an event subscription in AEG can deliver an event to only and only one endpoint. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: *FAN-OUT*:  multiple subscriptions are subscribed on the same source of interest (topic). *FAN-IN:* multiple subscriptions with the same destination resource (subscriber) are subscribed for different topics.